# React + Redux state deleted on page refresh

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, use-effect

I currently have a component that pulls a deck of cards from the backend and tries to create a chart out of values from those cards. On first load, everything works and the chart populates. On refresh, however, it seems that the decks prop is undefined (although redux devtools shows it's still present).

UseEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
  getDecks();                      // sets "decks"
  populateData();
}, []);
```

```
  const populateData = () => {
    var data = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
    cardArray = decks[0].cards;                // crashes here on reload; decks is undef.

    ...
    createChart(data);
  };
```

```
export const getDecks = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get("/api/decks");
    dispatch({
      type: GET_DECKS,
      payload: res.data,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: DECK_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status },
    });
  }
};
```

Initial state in deck reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  decks: [],
  currentCard: 0,
  loading: true,
  error: {},
  isFlipped: false,
};
```

I've looked at similar posts that suggest that I store decks in localstorage, but I have other components that call getDecks display data from them similar to this one without any issues. Does anybody have any tips or possible reasons why this might be doing this? Thanks.

Comment: Everytime you refresh the page, the useEffect() hook is called once the component has loaded. As a result your redux states are set back to their initial state until something causes this state to change. If there is something preventing this initial state from restoring your new values of ```decks``` then it will remain undefined. Can you give some more idea as to what or how getDecks() calls for your decks or may be share it here ?

Comment: If you're wondering how to share your code, you will have to edit your post and add it there.

Comment: I updated the post! getDecks() justs makes a get request to my backend that sends back a decks object containing an array of decks (for multiple decks) and assigns it to `decks` in the redux store. Each deck in `decks` has an array called `cards` that hold the card objects.

Comment: Inside the component that calls the useEffect(), are you receiving the ```decks``` props ?

Comment: Can you share the code where you initialize your decks state?

Comment: Yes, the component seems to receive the `decks` prop because it is passed in to the function component and is accounted for in mapStateToProps. I updated the post to show the initialState.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this and see if it works. The component that calls the `useEffect()` should look like so:

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
const deckComponent = ({decks}) => {
useEffect(() => {
  getDecks();                 
}, []);
useEffect(() => {                
  populateData();
}, [decks]);

// rest of the component goes here
 return(
.............
    );
};


deckComponent.propTypes = {
  decks: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  getDecks: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  decks: state.decks,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  getDecks,
})(deckComponent);
```

What this does is that anytime your component is loaded, the getDecks() function is called to the backend `decks` state changes. The 2nd useEffect watches for this change on the redux store and calls populateData().

Comment: Unfortunately it seems like this didn't fix it for me. populateData() still seems to think `decks` is undefined. I wonder if this is an issue with getDecks() not setting the state in time for populateData() to read it? (since getDecks() is async). I'm confused why it would consistently crash on only page reload if this were the case though.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. It's common apparently for redux stores to disappear on refresh, so wrapping your app in a persistent store (such as redux-persist) automatically fixes the problem for me. Thanks for everyone's suggestions.